# How to calculate the raster statistics with polygon layer using numpy and scipy in python?

Tags: raster, pyqgis, numpy, scipy.spatial

I have used zonal statistics from processing to calculate the raster statastics with polygon layer.

```
processing.runalg('qgis:zonalstatistics', rlayersource, 1, vlayer, None, True, Path)
```

But this is taking more time if the no of polygon blocks are more. So i found that we can use  `numpy` and `scipy` to calculate the statistics of the raster.

How can i do that?

Comment: I found the [`rasterstats`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/rasterstats) package to be quite a bit faster than QGIS' implementation of raster statistics.Maybe take a look at that before you try to reinvent the wheel in Python.

Answer (score 1):

If you have `numpy` and `scipy` properly configured you could try out the LecoS plugin. Depending on your system you might also have to install the python imaging library (however it is often co-installed).

Ether run it in directly in the processing toolbox 
[image]

or via the console (should be sth. like this for the mean. Not tested!)

```
processing.runalg('lecos:overlayrastermetricspolygons', 'raster', 'polygons', False,0,0,False, '~/out.csv')
```

Alternatively you could look into LecoS source how to use `numpy` and `scipy` for extracting data from raster layers. Uploaded it on [github](https://github.com/Martin-Jung/LecoS).